# Parsing inner double Dictionary using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, double

I have a `Dictionary<double, Dictionary<double,double>>` where the keys of the inner dictionaries are the same and I want to parse this such that the output is:

```
key1,dict1val1,dict2val1
key2,dict1val2,dict2val2
...
```

Sorry, I should have said that outer keys are not needed.

Here's an example of what I am after:

```
(1.0, (1.0, 1.1)),(2.0, (1.0,1.2))
(1.0, (1.1, 1.3)),(2.0, (1.1,1.4))
(1.0, (1.2, 1.5)),(2.0, (1.2,1.6))
```

should give an output of:

```
1.0,1.1,1.2
1.1,1.3,1.4
1.2,1.5,1.6
```

Is there an elegant way to do this in LINQ?  I've seen similar questions for string dictionaries, but the syntax doesn't work for doubles.

I've also ordered a book on the topic, but I need to do this ASAP.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the syntax doesn't work for doubles"_?

Comment: side note: It's not a good idea to have `Double` keys (round-up errors)

Comment: what is `Dictionary<double, Dictionary<double,double>>` before output? can you show some example?

Comment: @AndreiV - First, thanks for the edit. Second, I had found a previous question (which I can't find now) where Dict string, Dict string, string was used, but I couldn't make that solution work for doubles.

Comment: @Dimitry - Agreed, but it is what I have to work with.

Comment: @Tim.Tang - Example would be (1.0, (1.0, 1.1)), (2.0, (1.0, 1.2)) and the desired output would be: 1.0,1.1,1.2 then next line for next inner dict set. Outer keys are not needed.

Comment: All the keys in dict1 are in dict2 and the other way too?
Are keys in dict2 that are not dict1?

Comment: Yes.  Consider several sets of XY pairs plotted on a Cartesian graph with a common horizontal scale and you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) to expand these kinds of structures:

```
var expanded = dictionary.SelectMany(outer => 
    outer.Value.Select(inner => new { 
       OuterKey = outer.Key, 
       InnerKey = inner.Key, 
       Value =inner.Value 
    })
);
```

now you can do:

```
foreach (var item in expanded)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", item.OuterKey, item.InnerKey, item.Value);
}
```

---

After that, if you want to extract the inner key / values combination, you can just do:

```
var byInnerKey = expanded.ToLookup(item=> item.InnerKey, item => item.Value)
```

which is real easy to print using something like

```
foreach (var item in byInnerKey)
{
   string values = string.Join(", ",item);
   Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ", " + values);
}
```

([live example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3xjWKV))

---

Note: this uses [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `string.Join` method that is only available in .net 4 and above.

For .net 3.5 and below you can either loop the values, with a `string` / `StringBuilder`, or cast them out to a strings array explicitly

```
string values = string.Join(", ",item.Select(d => d.ToString()).ToArray());
```

([live example 3.5](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2e6tD7))

Comment: Not what I had in mind as a result - see my response to Tim.Tang above.

Comment: I honestly don't mean to be a pain and I really appreciate your excellent help, but I need a solution for net 3.5, and it doesn't recognize 'item' as a valid argument in the Join - sorry.

Comment: np, this uses the `IEnumerable<T>` overload that was added in 4.5. I'll edit with a version for 3.5

Comment: Trivial correction:  string values = string.Join(", ", item.Select(d => d.ToString()).ToArray());

Answer (score 1):

```
        var d1 = new Dictionary<double, double> { { 1.0, 1.1 } };
        var d2 = new Dictionary<double, double> { { 1.0, 1.2 } };

        var d3 = new Dictionary<double, double> { { 1.1, 1.3 } };
        var d4 = new Dictionary<double, double> { { 1.1, 1.4 } };

        var dict1 = new Dictionary<double, Dictionary<double, double>> { { 1.0, d1 }, { 2.0, d3 } };
        var dict2 = new Dictionary<double, Dictionary<double, double>>() { { 3.0, d2 }, { 4.0, d4 } };

        var keys = dict1.Values.SelectMany(dict => dict.Keys.ToList());
        var collection = keys.Select(key1 => new
        {
            Key = key1,
            Values = keys.SelectMany(key =>
                dict1.Values.Where(k1 => k1.ContainsKey(key1)).Select(k1 => k1[key1]).Union(
                dict2.Values.Where(k2 => k2.ContainsKey(key1)).Select(k2 => k2[key1]))
                ).Distinct().ToList()
        }).ToList();


        foreach (var x in collection)
        {
            Console.Write(x.Key + ": ");
            foreach (var y in x.Values)
            {
                Console.Write(y + ",");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: This works too, but SWeko's answer is slightly more compact, so I chose it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something is weird about this question.. and it doesn't make sense..
if you are using `Dictionary<double, Dictionary<double,double>>`
then there would be a 
key1, innerdictkey, innerdictvalue

but you are referring to a dict1val1? which is the inner dictionary it self..

in anycase you could loop through the dictionary like this

```
foreach(var kv in outerdic){
Console.WriteLine(kv.Key + ',' + kv.Value); // kv.Value would be a Dictionary<double, double>
Console.WriteLine(kv.Value[kv.Key]); // this would print the inner value of inner dictionary
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified with an example - see my response to Tim.Tang above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it, the structure looks like this:

```
dict[1.0]  ==> dictionary  [1.0] ==> 1.1
                           [1.1] ==> 1.3
                           [1.2] ==> 1.5

dict[2.0]  ==> dictionary  [1.0] ==> 1.2
                           [1.1] ==> 1.4
                           [1.2] ==> 1.6
```

Then we just step through the first dictionary, and match it to the second dictionary.

```
 var dict2 = dict[2.0];

 var lstResults = dict[1.0].Select(kvp=> String.Format("{0},{1},{2}",
                                      kvp.Key, kvp.Value, dict2[kvp.Key])
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Not two separate dictionaries, but rather multiple dictionaries nested within one larger one, and there can be more than two inner ones.  The key of the outer dictionary is only a placeholder in this case, but it nonetheless needs to be a double because it is actually used elsewhere (details not important to this question).

Comment: So the output should be `key1,dict1val1,dict2val1,...dictNval1`  ??

Comment: ... followed by key2,dict1value2...dictNval2, etc. for as many rows as there are values in a single inner dictionary.